# How do i convert HWND to LPCSTR in C++

Tags: c++, hwnd, lpcstr

What should i do to convert a HWND data type to LPCSTR. I need to print it to debug window using `OutputDebugStringA` function

Comment: If anything, something like `sscanf` with `%p` and the handle cast to `void *`. Alternatively a string stream with the same deal.

Comment: @chris Don't you mean `sprintf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << hwnd;
OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
```